# pagination using post id

Tags: php, database

Am new to php, i am try to use pagenation , where i post a unique id to a page then use that to load content with the respective id then pagenate all the content with that respective id.

Here below is what have been trying

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET["post"]))
 {
$page  = $_GET["post"];
} else
 {
$page = 1;
 };
 $limit = 2;
 $total_records = $pagination;
  $total_pages = ceil($total_records/$limit);
  $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);

$page != 0;
$prev = $page - 1;                 //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
  //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.

if($prev == 0)
 $prev = 1;
 $next <= $lastpage;
   //if no page var is given, default to 1.



$pagLink = "<ul class='pagination pagination-circle' class='justify-  content-center'>";

$pagLink .= "<li class='page-item  active'>
  <a class='page-link black' href='home.php?post=".$prev."'    aria-label='Back'>
    <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
    <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
  </a>
</li>";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  

 $pagLink .= "<li class='page-item active'><a  class='page-link'    href='home.php?post=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li> ";

};


 $pagLink .= "<li class='page-item pg-red active'>
  <a class='page-link black' href='home.php?post=".$next."'  aria-label='Next'>
    <span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span>
    <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
  </a>
</li>";
  echo $pagLink . "</ul>";

   ?>
```

Here is how i want to pagenate contents per id
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ungcb.png)

Comment: aaaand what's wrong with the code? errors? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Isaac thank you for your response, what am trying to achieve is that, i want to pagenate contents of a posts per id, and be able to loop through contents per id.